# Pandas: Generate a Dataframe column which has values depending on another column of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to generate a pandas Dataframe where a column will have numerical values based on the values of a column in another dataframe. Below is an example:
I want to generate another dataframe based on a column of dataframe df_

```
ipdb> df_ = pd.DataFrame({'c1':[False, True, False, True]})
ipdb> df_
      c1
0  False
1   True
2  False
3   True
```

Using df_ another dataframe df1 is generated with columns as below.

```
ipdb> df1
   col1  col2
0     0   NaN
1     1   0
2     2   NaN
3     3   1
```

Here, 'col1' has normal index values and 'c1' has NaN in the rows where there was False in df_ and sequentially incrementing values where 'c1' is True.

To generate this dataframe, below is what I have tried.

```
ipdb> df_[df_['c1']==True].reset_index().reset_index()
   level_0  index    c1
0        0      1  True
1        1      3  True
```

However, I feel there should be a better way to generate a dataframe with the two columns as in df1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and subtract `1` for start counting from `0`:

```
df_ = pd.DataFrame({'c1':[False, True, False, True]})

df_['col2'] = df_.loc[df_['c1'], 'c1'].cumsum().sub(1)
print (df_)
      c1  col2
0  False   NaN
1   True   0.0
2  False   NaN
3   True   1.0
```

Another solution is count occurencies of `True` values by `sum` with [`numpy.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) and assign back to filtered `DataFrame`:

```
df_.loc[df_['c1'],'col2']= np.arange(df_['c1'].sum())
print (df_)
      c1  col2
0  False   NaN
1   True   0.0
2  False   NaN
3   True   1.0
```

**Details**:

```
print (df_['c1'].sum())
2

print (np.arange(df_['c1'].sum()))
[0 1]
```

Comment: updated, your second solution is impressive, it's an alternative of `len`, cheers +1

Comment: @jezrael I am using your second method. The values in the new column are float. Is there a way to have these values as int type? I tried giving dtype=np.int32 as an argument to np.arange() but this also didn't help.

Comment: @GAURAVSRIVASTAVA - Unfortuantely not, because NaN values - it coerce all values to `float`. Possible solution is add `1` for count from `1` and replace `NaN`s to `0` like `df_['col2'] = df_['col2'].add(1).fillna(0).astype(int)`

Answer (score 2):

another way to solve this,

```
df.loc[df['c1'],'col2']=range(len(df[df['c1']]))
```

Output:

```
      c1  col2
0  False   NaN
1   True   0.0
2  False   NaN
3   True   1.0
```

Comment: I think `range(len(df[df['c1']==True]))` should be simplify by `range(len(df[df['c1']]))`